# What changes can I make to simply this function that groups parameter key value pairs

Tags: ruby

I am writing a function that can be used in a ruby script that will match the parameter and values together so the script can use them in an intelligent way. The idea is if you were to run a script with this function it would output the key value pairs of the parameters passed to the script.

For example

```
my_script.rb -user Jeff -key /path/to/key -config /path/to/config
```

The expected output would be an array with the key value pairs like

```
[ {:arg => 'user', :val => 'Jeff'}, {:arg => 'key', :val => '/path/to/key'}, {:arg => 'config', :val => '/path/to/config'} ]
```

This then could be used in any Ruby script that takes command line arguments and organizes it for them in a consistent way. Then the script can decide what to do with the output and act on those key value pairs passed.

**My Question:**

Are there are enhancements that can be made for this script and / or is there simpler ways to do this in Ruby? The function is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Script_Helper
  def self.get_params (ary)
    args = Array.new
    unless ARGV.empty?
      for i in 0..ARGV.size-1
        if ARGV[i].start_with?('-') and i < ARGV.size + 1
          args.push ({:arg => ARGV[i], :val => ARGV[i+1]})
        end
      end
    end
    return args
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

## Consistency

Sometimes you are using whitespace around operators, sometimes you don't. Sometimes you are using whitespace between the message name and the argument list of a message send, sometimes you don't.

You should choose one style and stick with it. If you are editing some existing code, you should adapt your style to be the same as the existing code. If you are part of a team, you should adapt your style to match the rest of the team.

Most communities have developed standardized community style guides. In Ruby, there are multiple such style guides. They all agree on the basics (e.g. indentation is 2 spaces), but they might disagree on more specific points (single quotes or double quotes).

In general, if you use two different ways to write the exact same thing, the reader will think that you want to convey a message with that. So, you should only use two different ways of writing the same thing *IFF* you actually *want* to convey some extra information.

For example, some people always use parentheses for defining and calling purely functional side-effect free methods, and never use parentheses for defining and calling impure methods. That is a *good* reason to use two different styles (parentheses and no parentheses) for doing the same thing (defining methods).

## Whitespace around operators

There should be 1 space either side of an operator.

## Whitespace in hash literals

In a hash literal, there should be one space after the opening curly brace and one space before the closing curly brace.

## New-style hash literals

Well, they are called "new-style" or "Ruby 1.9" hash literals, but really, they were introduced in 2007, and we have Ruby 3.0 soon, so we should really simply be calling them "hash literals" at this point. They are neither new anymore nor is Ruby 1.9 still relevant.

Ruby 1.9 introduced a shortcut syntax for hash literals where keys are symbols, inspired by ECMAScript.

So, this:

```ruby
{:arg => ARGV[i], :val => ARGV[i+1]}
```

should be this:

```ruby
{ arg: ARGV[i], val: ARGV[i+1] }
```

## Frozen string literals

Immutable data structures and purely functional code are always preferred, unless mutability and side-effects are required for clarity or performance. In Ruby, strings are always mutable, but there is a magic comment you can add to your files (also available as a command-line option for the Ruby engine), which will automatically make all literal strings immutable:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

It is generally preferred to add this comment to all your files.

## No space before parameter list

In a method definition, there should be no whitespace between the method name and the parameter list, e.g. this:

```ruby
def self.get_params (ary)
```

should be

```ruby
def self.get_params(ary)
```

Ruby allows you to specify a parameter list either in parentheses or with whitespace. If you combine the two, it could get confusing, because Ruby also allows *array destructuring* in parameter lists:

```ruby
def foo(((first_of_first, second_of_first), second))
  second_of_first
end

foo([[23, 42], 'Hello'])
#=> 42
```

Array destructuring is performed by adding an additional set of parentheses. Now, if you have a method with two parameters, you can write it like this:

```ruby
def foo(bar, baz)
end
```

or like this:

```ruby
def foo bar, baz
end
```

If you write it like this:

```ruby
def foo (bar, baz)
end
```

A reader *might* think that this is a *single* parameter that uses array destructuring. In fact, Ruby even prints a warning that tells you exactly that:

```
warning: parentheses after method name is interpreted as an argument list, not a decomposed argument
```

## No space before argument list

In a message send, there should be no whitespace between the message and the argument list, e.g. this:

```ruby
args.push ({:arg => ARGV[i], :val => ARGV[i+1]})
```

should be

```ruby
args.push({:arg => ARGV[i], :val => ARGV[i+1]})
```

This will bite you as soon as you have more than one argument. Ruby allows you to write the argument list to a message send without parentheses like this:

```ruby
foo.bar baz, quux
```

instead of

```ruby
foo.bar(baz, quux)
```

The problem arises because the whitespace triggers the first mode, so

```ruby
foo.bar (baz, quux)
```

is *not* interpreted as *two* arguments `baz` and `quux` but as passing arguments with whitespace *instead of parentheses* and thus as a *single argument* `(baz, quux)`. Except `(baz, quux)` is not legal Ruby code, and thus you get an error.

## Warnings

The Ruby developers work hard on providing helpful warning messages. You should read them and investigate them. They almost always point to problems or at least potential problems in your code.

For example, running your code generates the following warning message:

```
warning: parentheses after method name is interpreted as an argument list, not a decomposed argument
```

## Unused parameter

Your `get_params` method is defined with one parameter `ary`, but you are not using this parameter anywhere. It is completely useless.

If you have a parameter or a local variable that is *intentionally* unused, the Ruby community standard is to name it with a leading underscore, e.g. `_ary` or even just `_`.

However, in this case, it serves absolutely no purpose and should simply be removed altogether.

## Empty literals

Instead of using the `new` method to create instances of core classes, you should prefer to use literals. E.g. use `''` or `""` instead of `String.new`, `[]` instead of `Array.new`, and so forth.

This is *especially* true for *empty* objects.

```ruby
args = Array.new
```

should be

```ruby
args = []
```

## Prefer `each` over `for` / `in`

Nobody in Ruby uses `for` / `in`. In fact, we hardly use any loops at all. I would go so far as to say, when you are using a loop, you are doing it wrong.

The idiomatic way would be to use [`Range#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-each) instead. Not only is `each` more idiomatic, but `for` / `in` has this weird scoping rule where the loop variable escapes into the surrounding scope, which is almost always not what you want.

So, this:

```ruby
for i in 0..ARGV.size-1
  if ARGV[i].start_with?('-') and i < ARGV.size + 1
    args.push ({:arg => ARGV[i], :val => ARGV[i+1]})
  end
end
```

should become this:

```ruby
(0..ARGV.size-1).each do |i|
  if ARGV[i].start_with?('-') and i < ARGV.size + 1
    args.push ({:arg => ARGV[i], :val => ARGV[i+1]})
  end
end
```

Actually, there is a lot more that can be improved about that, but we will stick with the purely mechanical transformations for now, and keep our brain switched off.

## Modifier `if`

If you have a conditional expression with only a single expression in the body and no `else`, it is generally preferred to use the modifier form.

```ruby
if ARGV[i].start_with?('-') and i < ARGV.size + 1
  args.push ({:arg => ARGV[i], :val => ARGV[i+1]})
end
```

should be

```ruby
args.push ({:arg => ARGV[i], :val => ARGV[i+1]}) if ARGV[i].start_with?('-') and i < ARGV.size + 1
```

## Prefer symbolic operators `||`, `&&`, `!` over keywords `and`, `or`, `not`

In a boolean expression, you should prefer the symbolic operators over the keywords. The keywords have doubly-unexpected precedence: not only is the precedence of the keywords `and` and `or` much lower than the precedence of `&&` and `||`, but also `and` and `or` both have the *same* precedence while `&&` has higher precedence than `||`. This can be very confusing.

Idiomatic Ruby community standard is to always use the symbolic operators, *except* for when you actually use boolean logic for control flow, as in

```ruby
do_something and exit
```

So,

```ruby
ARGV[i].start_with?('-') and i < ARGV.size + 1
```

should be

```ruby
ARGV[i].start_with?('-') && i < ARGV.size + 1
```

## Redundant `return`

The return value of a method is the value of the last expression that was evaluated inside the method. Unless you want an early `return`, it is generally not necessary to use `return` at all.

## Linting

You should run some sort of linter or static analyzer on your code. [Rubocop](https://www.rubocop.org/) is a popular one, but there are others.

Rubocop was able to detect all of the style violations I pointed out above (plus some more), and also was able to autocorrect all of the ones I listed.

Let me repeat that: I have just spent two pages pointing out how to correct tons of stuff that you can *actually* correct within milliseconds at the push of a button. I have set up my editor such that it automatically runs Rubocop with auto-fix as soon as I hit "save".

In particular, running Rubocop on your code, it detects 19 offenses, of which it can automatically correct 17. This leaves you with 2 offenses, both of which are very simple.

Here's what the result of the auto-fix looks like:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Script_Helper
  def self.get_params(_ary)
    args = []
    unless ARGV.empty?
      (0..ARGV.size - 1).each do |i|
        args.push({ arg: ARGV[i], val: ARGV[i + 1] }) if ARGV[i].start_with?('-') && (i < ARGV.size + 1)
      end
    end
    args
  end
end
```

And here are the offenses that Rubocop could not automatically correct:

```
Offenses:

script_helper.rb:4:1: C: Style/Documentation: Missing top-level class documentation comment.
class Script_Helper
^^^^^

script_helper.rb:4:7: C: Naming/ClassAndModuleCamelCase: Use CamelCase for classes and modules.
class Script_Helper
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

1 file inspected, 2 offenses detected
```

Let's look at the simple one first.

## Naming

Class names should be `PascalCase`, constants should be `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`, everything else should be `snake_case`. Files should be named after the primary module or class they define, and they should be named in `snake_case` as well.

So, the name of your class should be `ScriptHelper`, not `Script_Helper`.

## Unused parameter, take 2

As mentioned above, the parameter should be removed. Rubocop only automatically renamed it, because removing it could break code that calls this method with an argument.

But since it isn't used, it should simply be removed and all callers fixed to not pass an argument.

## Vertical whitespace

Your method could use some vertical whitespace to give the code more room to breathe. I would suggest at least separating the initialization at the beginning of the method, and the return at the end:

```ruby
def self.get_params(_ary)
  args = []

  unless ARGV.empty?
    (0..ARGV.size - 1).each do |i|
      args.push({ arg: ARGV[i], val: ARGV[i + 1] }) if ARGV[i].start_with?('-') && (i < ARGV.size + 1)
    end
  end

  args
end
```

## "Reader" methods

I re-run Rubocop every time I change something in my code. In fact, I have it set up to run automatically when I save my code, when I commit my code, etc.

Since we now have removed the parameter from the method, it now tells us something new: "Reader" methods or "getter methods" that don't take any arguments and simply return a value should not be named with a `get_` prefix. This is unlike Java, for example.

So, the method should simply be named `params`.

## Redundant check

If `ARGV` is empty, its size will be `0`, which means that the range `0..ARGV.size - 1` will be the range `0..-1`, which is empty. Iterating over an empty range doesn't do anything, so we can just delete the check for `ARGV.empty?`

## Redundant check 2

You are iterating from 0 to size-1, therefore `i` will *never* be greater than size. The check `i < ARGV.size + 1` will always be true, and is thus redundant and can be deleted.

## Iterators, take 2

We already converted the `for` loop into an `each` iterator. However, you are iterating over the *indices* of `ARGV` and then pull out the elements using the indices. This is a very FORTRAN way of writing that code. It is much easier to iterate over the *elements* directly.

Even better, since you always need the to look at the current and the next element, we can iterate over a *sliding window of 2 consecutive elements*. That's exactly what [`Enumerable#each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) does:

```ruby
ARGV.each_cons(2) do |param, arg|
  args.push({ arg: param, val: arg }) if param.start_with?('-')
end
```

As above, if `ARGV` is empty, `each_cons` will simply not do anything, so we don't need to check.

## The "shovel" operator `<<`

And while we are looking at this code: [`Array#push`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-push) is not idiomatic. More precisely, it is *only* idiomatic if you are using the array as a *stack*, then you would use `Array#push` and [`Array#pop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pop), since those are the standard names for the stack operations.

The idiomatic way of appending something to something else is the shovel operator, in this case [`Array#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C), so that should be

```ruby
args << { arg: param, val: arg }
```

## Iterators, take 3

We are still doing a lot of stuff manually. Initialize the empty array, loop over `ARGV`, append to the array, etc.

Whenever you have the pattern of "Initialize a result, loop over a collection appending to the result, return result", that is a [*fold*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)). There are two implementations of *fold* in the Ruby core library, [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) and [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). `inject` is the more functional one, `each_with_object` is the more imperative one. So, for now, we will use `each_with_object` here, since the code is still pretty imperative, and that makes the relationship between the old and new code more clear:

```ruby
args = []

ARGV.each_cons(2) do |param, arg|
  args << { arg: param, val: arg } if param.start_with?('-')
end

args
```

becomes

```ruby
ARGV.each_cons(2).each_with_object([]) do |(param, arg), args|
  args << { arg: param, val: arg } if param.start_with?('-')
end
```

Now, if we want to make it purely functional, it would look like this:

```ruby
ARGV.each_cons(2).inject([]) do |args, (param, arg)|
  if param.start_with?('-') then args + [{ arg: param, val: arg }] else args end
end
```

## Iterators, take 4

Instead of filtering inside the iteration, we could instead *chain* iterators and filter first. This works for both our variations:

```ruby
ARGV
  .each_cons(2)
  .select { |param, _| param.start_with?('-') }
  .each_with_object([]) { |(param, arg), args| args << { arg: param, val: arg } }

ARGV
  .each_cons(2)
  .select { |param, _| param.start_with?('-') }
  .inject([]) { |args, (param, arg)| args + [{ arg: param, val: arg }] }
```

## Excursion: Generality of *fold* (`inject` / `each_with_object`)

When I wrote above that you can rewrite this iteration with `inject` or `each_with_object`, that was actually a tautological statement. I didn't even have to read the code to make this statement.

It turns out that *fold* is "general". [*Every* iteration over a collection can be expressed using *fold*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Universality). This means, if we were to delete *every method* from `Enumerable`, except `inject`, then we could re-implement the entire `Enumerable` module again, using nothing but `inject`. As long as we have `inject`, we can do anything.

## Iterators, take 5

So, what we did until now was replace the loop with a low-level iterator, replace the low-level iterator with a higher-level iterator, and decompose the iteration into two chained higher-level iterators.

However, we are still not done. What we are now doing is we take each element from our filtered sliding window collection, modifying it, and putting it into a new collection. So, really, what we are doing is *transforming* each element, or "mapping" each element to a new element.

This is called [*map*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) and is also available in Ruby as [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

So, finally, our code looks like this:

```ruby
ARGV
  .each_cons(2)
  .select { |param, _| param.start_with?('-') }
  .map { |param, arg| { arg: param, val: arg } }
end
```

What we did here, was to replace the *general* high-level iterator *fold* (which can do *anything*) with a more restricted, more specialized high-level iterator *map*. By using a more specialized iterator, we are able to better convey our semantics to the reader. Instead of thinking "Okay, so here we have an accumulator, and an element, and we do something with the element, and then append it to the accumulator … ah, I see, we are transforming each element", the reader just sees `map` and instantly *knows* that `map` transforms the elements.

## Classes and modules

In your code, you are using a class. However, your class cannot sensibly be instantiated. Therefore, it shouldn't be a class.

It makes more sense for it to be a module instead. Here's how I would write your entire file:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

module ScriptHelper
  module_function def params =
    ARGV
      .each_cons(2)
      .select { |param, _| param.start_with?('-') }
      .map { |param, arg| { arg: param, val: arg } }
end
```

## Linter, revisited

Rubocop actually complains about my inline use of [`Module#module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-module_function). It wants me to write this instead:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

module ScriptHelper
  def params =
    ARGV
      .each_cons(2)
      .select { |param, _| param.start_with?('-') }
      .map { |param, arg| { arg: param, val: arg } }

  module_function :params
end
```

I disagree. You should not be afraid to disable or re-configure rules in your linter to fit your style.

However, note that programming is a team sport. If you are *modifying* code, adopt the existing style. If you are part of a team, adopt the team's style. If you write open source code, adopt the project's style. If you start your own project, adopt the community's style (do *not* create your own style for your project, until your project is big and successful enough to have its own independent community).

## Speaking of community …

Of course, the *really correct* solution to your problem is to use one of the many, already existing, well-maintained, well-tested, well-documented, well-known command line option parser libraries. Ruby ships with [`optparse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/) in the standard library, but there are many, many others with some amazing features:

- [Clamp](https://github.com/mdub/clamp)
- [Commander](https://github.com/commander-rb/commander)
- [`Mixlib::CLI`](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-cli)
- [Optimist](https://manageiq.org/optimist/)
- [slop](https://github.com/leejarvis/slop)

Don't re-invent the wheel.

[It is true that NASA has (kind-of) re-invented the wheel for the Perseverance rover](https://nasa.gov/specials/wheels/), but most of us are not NASA. We don't face the unique challenge of sending a rover to Mars that needs to autonomously drive over rough, unknown terrain, and needs to be as light while at the same time as robust as possible. We just want to get from A to B on a paved road. There are plenty of wheels available off-the-shelf that do that.

Always remember: we are not NASA. It is highly unlikely that a problem we are encountering has never before been seen in the history of humankind. Parsing command line arguments is not a highly-specialized, complex, unique problem, it is a problem that has been solved with standardized libraries over 30 years ago.